# вопрос про скорость работы алгоритмов

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Имеется задача: создать класс с указанными методами:

```
class NumArray {
  
    public NumArray(int[] nums) {
    //инициализация объекта с массивом интов
    }

    public void update(int index, int val) {
    // изменить значение под индексом index на значение val
    }

    public int sumRange(int left, int right) {
    //посчитать сумму между левым и правым индексом включительно
    }
}
```

Казалось бы ничего трудного, но я и реализовал это самым очевидным способом:

```
class NumArray {
    int[] nums;
    public NumArray(int[] nums) {
        this.nums=nums;
    }

    public void update(int index, int val) {
        nums[index]=val;
    }

    public int sumRange(int left, int right) {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=left;i<=right;i++)
            sum+=nums[i];
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Класс прошел 13/15 проверок и на 14 когда я получил на вход большие массивы и большую разницу между left и right  я не прошел проверку - не вписался в лимит по времени. Подсмотрел в ответы - там люди бинарные деревья организовывают и прочие "сложности". И я не могу понять ЗАЧЕМ? По сути методы в моем виде итак максимально быстрые? (update - это O(1) - и быстрее сделать невозможно) и (sumRange - это О(n) - так же быстрее сделать невозможно). В чем я ошибаюсь? Заранее спасибо

Comment: *В чем я ошибаюсь?* В том, что *sumRange - это О(n) - так же быстрее сделать невозможно*...

Comment: в случае с большой разницей `left` `right` выгоднее было вычитать ненужные числа из существующей суммы (которую нужно создать в начале и обновлять при вызове `update`) например

Comment: update и sumRange могут оба работать за `log(N)`.

Comment: Вообразите что вместе с оригинальным массивом вы храните накопительные суммы. Тогда update потребует N чтобы обновить суммы справа от изменения. Зато `sumRange` будет работать за константу. Это не рабочее решение для данного задания, а пример для "расширения сознания".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну я о похожем думал, есть обходные пути. Но из всего что я придумал, все равно один из методов, либо первый, либо второй работает за О(n). При решении задачи никуда не уйти от перебора элементов, разница только в каком месте я это буду делать. А O(1) + O(n) ничем не будет в итоге отличаться от О(n) + O(1). Или нет?

Comment: Потому я и сказал что это пример. Реальное решение опирается на [дерево отрезков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2). Обе операции - логарифм.

Comment: У e-maxx описано как хранить [дерево](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree) без дополнительной памяти на само дерево. Самый практичный вариант. Если вы работали с [кучей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0) (которая пирамида или приоритетная очередь) то вам всё покажется знакомым.

Comment: Не буду лишать вас удовольствия разобраться в задаче самому. Такое бывает только раз. :)

Comment: да спасибо, уже пишу реализацию)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем благодаря подсказкам в комментариях решил задачу. Воспользовался структурой данных "дерево отрезков". Действительно при таком варианте решения я все также никуда не делся от сложности O(n) - именно такая сложность при построении дерева. Поэтому этот вариант помогает выиграть в скорости, когда у нас есть ОДИН исходный массив, и множество манипуляций с ним. То есть строится дерево 1 раз со сложностью О(n), а далее все манипуляции проводятся уже за логарифмическое время. И благодаря этому я проскочил те тесты, где задается один массив, и множественные вызовы методов на нем. Собственно сама реализация класса, если вдруг кому понадобится:

```
   public NumArray(int[] nums) {
        this.nums = nums;
        if (nums == null || nums.length == 0) return;
        this.root = buildTree(0, nums.length - 1);   //запуск построения дерева
        //System.out.println(this.root);
    }

    private TreeNode buildTree(int start, int end) {       //построение дерева
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
        treeNode.start = start;
        treeNode.end = end;

        if (start == end) {
            treeNode.sum = nums[start];
            //System.out.println(treeNode.sum);
            return treeNode;
        }
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        treeNode.left = buildTree(start, mid);
        treeNode.right = buildTree(mid + 1, end);

        treeNode.sum = treeNode.left.sum + treeNode.right.sum;
        //System.out.println(treeNode.sum);

        return treeNode;
    }

    public void update(int i, int val) {
        update(root, i, val);               //стартовый запуск метода update, в котором уже будут крутиться рекурсии
    }

    private void update(TreeNode node, int i, int val) {
        if (node == null) return;
        if (node.end == node.start) {
            node.sum = val;
            return;
        }
        int mid = node.start + (node.end - node.start) / 2;
        if (i <= mid)
            update(node.left, i, val);
        else update(node.right, i, val);
        node.sum = node.left.sum + node.right.sum;
    }

    public int sumRange(int start, int end) {
        return sumRange(root, start, end);        // аналогично стартовый запуск метода sumRange, в котором будет крутиться рекурсия.
    }

    private int sumRange(TreeNode node, int start, int end) {
        if (start < node.start || end > node.end) {
            return -1;
        }

        if ((start == node.start) && (end == node.end)) {
            return node.sum;
        }

        int mid = node.start + (node.end - node.start) / 2;
        if (start > mid)
            return sumRange(node.right, start, end);
        if (end <= mid) {
            return sumRange(node.left, start, end);
        }
        return sumRange(node.left, start, mid) + sumRange(node.right, mid + 1, end);

    }
}
```

Всем спасибо, за подсказки!